# Git bash (mintty). How to open maximized

Tags: git, git-bash

I updated git for windows and found that it now has `mintty` as the command prompt for git bash. It is much better than previous windows command prompt based git bash.

It would be great if I could open the git bash initially maximized. There is a command line argument for mintty to open maximized.

```
-w, --window normal|min|max|full
```

But, I don't know how I can pass this argument to mintty when I open git bash from 'Open git bash here' context menu.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but I got it working by replacing `git-bash.exe` with my own one which gives `-w max` additional argument.

Here is the code for `git-bash.exe`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    system("START /B D:\\program_files\\git\\Git\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe -w max -o AppID=GitForWindows.Bash -o RelaunchCommand=\"D:\\program_files\\git\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" -o RelaunchDisplayName=\"Git Bash\" -i /mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico /usr/bin/bash --login -i");
    return 0;
}
```

You have to change paths in above code to your own values if you need to build your own `git-bash.exe` from above code.

EDIT:
If mintty is started with above code, it does not know the location of `git` binary. So I had to add the git bin directory to PATH variable.

Answer (score 45):

You may put an minttyrc file into etc folder of Git install (like C:\Program Files\Git\etc), with the following config:

```
Window=max
```

If you change your mind and want to set a specific window size you can alternatively put the number of columns and rows into minttyrc, for example:

```
Columns=132
Rows=60
```

btw, based on https://github.com/mintty/mintty/blob/7d70b3cb9776de288375ffe438d35e648650c98f/wiki/Tips.md, we may have several locations:

> For its configuration file, it reads /etc/minttyrc, $APPDATA/mintty/config, ~/.config/mintty/config, ~/.minttyrc, in this order.

Comment: Works well with a ~/.minttyrc file on windows 10

Comment: Same with Win7 Pro.

Comment: Mine works on Windows 10 only if filename is `minttyrc` (without the leading dot)

Comment: Windows 10. It turns out I've already had a `.minttyrc` in my home (~) folder (probably because I had re-configured the text font in git-bash), I simply added `Window=max` in the file, and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with a ~/.minttyrc (nor with a ~/minttyrc) file on windows 10 (version of git bash : 2.38.1).